# javascript string.search not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

i am having a peculiar issue with Chrome at the moment... here's what i'm trying to accomplish:

i have a series of table sections, which have been identified with their IDs accordingly, like this:

```
T = Tab  
G = Group within Tab  
S = Sub-Group within Group  
# = Numerical index  

for example:  
<tr id="T1"> = Tab 1  
<td id="T1G3"> = Tab 1 , Group 3  
<td id="T1G3S1"> = Tab 1, Group 3, Sub-Group 1
```

Pretty straight forward so far... with the help of JavaScript, i also aim to enable or disabled these groups on the form. Now, here's the problem i'm having... when my form loads the first time, i want to disable everything on the form that requires it. To do so, i created a dynamic function, that could do that for me, where i would specify which tags are affected, and what to look for within the IDs of those tags, and if a match occurs, disable it, like this:

```
Pseudo and Definition:
Function DisableAll(string TagNamesCSArray, string RegExpContent)
{
Split the tag names provided into an array
- loop through the array and get all tags using document.getElementsByTagName() within page
-- if tags are found
--- loop through collection of tags/elements found
---- if the ID of the element is present, and MATCHES the RegExp in any way
----- disable that item
---- end if
--- end loop
-- end if
- end loop
}
```

this was fairly easy to implement, and this is the final result:

```
function DisableAll(TagNames, RegExpStr) 
{
//declare local vars
var tagarr = TagNames.split(",");
var collection1;
var IdReg = new RegExp(RegExpStr);
var i;

//loop through getting all the tags
for (i = 0; i < tagarr.length; i++) 
{
    collection1 = document.getElementsByTagName(tagarr[i].toString())
    //loop through the collection of items found, if found
    if (collection1) 
    {
        for (y = 0; y < collection1.length; y++) 
        {
            if (collection1[y].getAttribute("id") != null) 
            {
                if (collection1[y].getAttribute("id").toString().search(IdReg) != -1) 
                {
                    collection1[y].disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return;
```

}

And then i place a call to it like this:

```
DisableAll("tr,td", "^T|^T[0-9]S");
```

seems simple yes? "Hannnn!" wrong answer batman... this works PERFECTLY, in all browsers, except for Chrome... now why is that? i don't understand. Maybe there's something wrong with my RegExp?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

MaxOvrdrv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the regex match all possibilities. But the line `collection1[y].disabled = true;` has no effect because disabled is not a property of a DOM Node.

BTW: The second part of your regex is unnecessary because "^T" will match every ID which begins with T following by a number.

Comment: thanks... as you responded to this, i just learned that IE disables elements differently than the other browsers... e.g.: i need to disable the controls within the matched ID, and not the control that has the matched ID... sad... because this would be so useful when performing tasks like these... :S